# Not able to connect with database

Tags: sql-server, excel, vb6, vba

I am new in Excel VBA. I have ready made code which is written for machine of IP address 199.63.106.70. Now i want same code to be run for another machine 199.56.122.155. I have install MS SQL server 2008 R2 on new machine. I also checked with connection using Data Connection Wizard. Data is Fetched.
But when i try to get data by click on button it display error message "Error in Process".
Controller is Jumping from `oCon.Open` 
 How can this error will be solved? is format of connection string is correct?
User Id and Password is windows login credentials which is used in string.

```
 Dim oCon As ADODB.Connection
    Dim oRS As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim rowcounter As Long

    On Error GoTo errhandler
    rowcounter = 2
    Set oCon = New ADODB.Connection
      oCon.connectionstring = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=199.63.106.70;Database=dashboard;User Id=dashboardadmin;Password=passwrd;"
      oCon.Open
      Set oRS = New ADODB.Recordset
      oRS.ActiveConnection = oCon

       oRS.Source = "SELECT HourlyReadingTimestamp, Hourlyreading,cost FROM MeterConsumptioNDetail where meterid=" & Range("J5").Value & " and HourlyreadingTimestamp between '" & Range("K5").Value & "' and '" & Range("L5").Value & " 23:59:59' order by HourlyreadingTimestamp"
       oRS.Open

        While Not oRS.EOF
           Range("A" & rowcounter).Value = oRS.Fields(0).Value
           Range("B" & rowcounter).Value = oRS.Fields(1).Value
           Range("C" & rowcounter).Value = oRS.Fields(2).Value

            rowcounter = rowcounter + 1

           oRS.MoveNext
        Wend

          oCon.Close
        If Not oRS Is Nothing Then Set oRS = Nothing
        If Not oCon Is Nothing Then Set oCon = Nothing
        MsgBox ("Data fetched successfully")
        Exit Sub
errhandler:
        MsgBox ("Error in process!")
End Sub
```

Comment: Comment out `On Error GoTo errhandler` so you see the *actual* error then please add it to your question.

Comment: After Comment out error handler Error Dialog box showing Run-time Error `'-2147467259 (80004005)': SQL Server does not exist or access denied.`

Comment: And using the connection string below?

Comment: My database is located in Virtual Machine and i am trying to access that from VM itself. Is there any other method to access database from VM Machine? When i copy and paste connection string which is automatically created in 'connection' window it execute ` oCon.Open ` but it give error in ` oRS.open ` in above code.

Answer (score 0):

The connection string is incorrect if you want to use Integrated Security (Windows Login) use:

```
Driver={SQL Server};Server=199.63.106.70;Database=dashboard;Trusted_Connection=Yes;
```

The driver will deal with authentication based on the user running the process.